# Implementing OG tags in a single page application

Tags: typescript, aurelia, facebook-opengraph

We're developing a single page application with Typescript and Aurelia framework. Currently, we're looking for a way to implement OG tags, but struggling since SPA has only one `<head>` in the index.ejs file and we have to find a way to set meta tags with dynamic content for each page.

jQuery was one of the options but Facebook crawler wouldn't catch the meta tag change since it doesn't wait for JS/TS to load. SSR was also considered but due to urgency of task and amount of work it would take,  it was discarded.

Did anyone encounter a similar issue or can provide a suggestion how to tackle this issue?

Comment: The Aurelia team can help you get SSR set up. consulting@aurelia.io

Answer (score 0):

Facebook ignores JavaScript for the OG Tags.

I know 2 solutions for this:

- [prerender.io](https://prerender.io)
- SSR (you mentioned that already)